# Getting second level nested object inside array of objects mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, nested, nested-lists

My database looks like this:

```json
[
     {
      "title": "man",
      "articlesType": [
             {
                 "title": "shoes",
                 "articles": [
                     {
                         "title": "shoes1",
                         "id": "randomId"
                     },
                     {
                         "title": "shoes2",
                         "id": "alsoRandomId"
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
    },

    {
    "title": "woman",
    "articlesType": [
         {
             "title": "pants",
              "articles": [
                    {
                        "title": "pants1",
                        "id": "anotherRandomId"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "pants1",
                        "id": "justId"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I expect something like this:   , is it possible to get whole object in this nested just using an ID?

```json
{
   "title": "shoes2",
   "id": "alsoRandomId"
}
```

I found this, but does not work for me

Comment: So do you need some kind of JavaScript function that can get a specified nested object with just the id?

Answer (score 0):

You can try an aggregation pipeline using double `$unwind` to deconstruct the array twice and then filter by your desired `id` (I'm assuming you want to match by the id).

And the last step, `$project` is to output the result in the same way as you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$articlesType"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$articlesType.articles"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "articlesType.articles.id": "alsoRandomId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "title": "$articlesType.articles.title",
      "id": "$articlesType.articles.id"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dzTYYc8URuY)